# How to call a C function in Fortran and properly pass uint32_t arguments

Tags: c, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding, uint32

Hi I am using a Fortran 90 code to call a C function. Since I am manipulating addresses, the arguments of the C function should be properly matched in Fortran. I am using ifort and icc to compile the code and working on 64 bit machine.

Some testing showed that this will work also with `int32_t`, although to prevent eventual pitfalls, I would like to keep the `uint32_t`

The C functions I am calling has the following prototypes

```
uint32_t encode_(uint32_t x, uint32_t y)
uint32_t decode_(uint32_t dec)
```

I can't call these functions simply by doing something like

```
integer :: cod,encode
cod = encode(i,j)
```

This will produce gibberish. Therefore I am using a workaround:

```
void code2d_(uint32_t j[] ){


uint32_t i;

i=encode_(j[0],j[1]);  
// the underscore is due to the FORTRAN naming convention

printf("Coded %10d  \n",i);

}
```

And subsequently in Fortran

```
 integer :: cod,code2d
 cod = code2d(i,j)
```

Well obviously I have some problem with the mismatch of the argument types. Unfortunately I don't know how to fix this. Since in my decode/encode functions binary address arithmetic is done it is quite important to preserve the `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You appear to know about iso_c_binding, as you use the tag. Study the Fortran 2003 interoperability with C. Read the tag description and some documentation like http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gfortran/Interoperability-with-C.html . There is no place in modern Fortran for your trailing underscores and similar stuff.

Fortran doesn't have any unsigned types, you have to use the signed. As long as the signed values are positive, it works. If you need larger values, use larger integer type. You can `transfer()` the lower bytes to int32 if you need it.

Third, Fortran uses some variants of pass by reference by default, especially for `bind(c)` procedures (it may be a reference to a copy or some other variant). You must use the `value` attribute to pass by value.

```
uint32_t encode(uint32_t x, uint32_t y)
uint32_t decode(uint32_t dec)

module c_procs
  interface
    function encode(x, y) bind(C, name="encode")
      use iso_c_binding
      integer(c_int32_t) :: encode
      integer(c_int32_t), value :: x, y
    end function
    function decode(x, y) bind(C, name="decode")
      use iso_c_binding
      integer(c_int32_t) :: decode
      integer(c_int32_t), value :: dec
    end function
  end interface
end module

...

use iso_c_binding
use c_procs

integer(c_int32_t) :: cod, i, j
cod = encode(i,j)
```

---

Recent versions of GCC are able to detect that we are mixing signed and unsigned types during link-time optimizations:

```
rng.f90:173:0: warning: type of 'sub' does not match original declaration [-Wlto-type-mismatch]
     ival = sub(jz, jsr)
^
rng_c.c:2:10: note: return value type mismatch
 uint32_t sub(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
          ^
/usr/include/stdint.h:51:23: note: type 'uint32_t' should match type 'int'
 typedef unsigned int  uint32_t;
                       ^
rng_c.c:2:10: note: 'sub' was previously declared here
 uint32_t sub(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
```

You can ignore the warning or disable it if you know what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you for the comment and the very handy solution. I was hoping to get the job done, without the ISO C binding. This is a FORTRAN 95-and later feature and might cause some problems. For instance I use a lot of F77 for fast array operations. There I use C for memory allocation and the usual binding works quite neatly, (the underscore stuff) as you might name it. Anyway I will rely on the modern FORTRAN and use the ISO C binding. BTW in the second interface you should have `integer(c_int32_t) :: decode` Thanks Vladimir !

Comment: You can always retain the underscores, just use them in the binding name. You can also just fix change your C procedues to accept pointers. In any case make sure to adhere to the interface exactly. The Fortran-C binding is very efficient, don't worry about performance.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a C function which takes a C_INT (or int in C) and then converts it to uint32_t.  Then you link to this from Fortran.

in C:

```
uint32_t to_uint32_t ( int i ) {
    return (uint32_t)i; //cast actually not needed since it implicitly converts
}
```

in fortran:

```
module convert
    interface
        integer(C_INT32_T) function integer_to_uint32_t_C ( i ) bind (c,name="to_uint32_t")
            use iso_c_binding
            use user32_constants_types
            integer(c_int), value :: i
        end function
    end interface

end module convert
```

Then you can use `integer_to_uint32_t_C` to pass Fortran integer values to C functions that expect the `uint32_t`.  Also, you might want to make a C function that converts in back to a plain ole `int` so you can use the results in Fortran.

Comment: What is the reason for the STDCALL? Note that the OP said they work on a 64 machine. But more importantly, how would one call encode_ and decode_ then with these?

Comment: @VladimirF Yeah I suppose it is not needed in this case, so got rid of it.  It's typically used when linking to dynamic libraries that use STDCALL.